# Run a specific SQL Server job step from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a job with 5 steps that are scheduled to run after each other.

I want to have a stored procedure where a user can execute the stored procedure and give the step number as a parameter.

Only this job step then will be executed and no further steps.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this to run a specific step in a job

```
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Job Name', @step_name = N'step_name'
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx

**Update**

If you want to run only a specific step, instead of starting from a step, try getting the step command and run that instead:

```
exec sp_help_job @job_name = 'job_name', @job_aspect = 'STEPS'
```

This will return the commands to run for the steps, then you can filter on the step name and run the step's command.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186722.aspx

Comment: [ @step_name= ] 'step_name'
The name of the step at which to begin execution of the job. However I only want to execute 1 step. If I start at step 3. Only step 3 may get exectued.

Comment: Please add note that the sp_start_job helper is located in msdb. so the exact command should be EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job